# Is veterinary as a noun a current AmE usage?

Tags: american-english, british-english

The more common term to call a doctor who’s specialized in taking care of the health of animals is ***[veterinarian](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/veterinarian)***  often shortened to ***vet***.

***[veterinary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/veterinary)*** is the related adjective accoding to the Cambridge Dictionary and the [OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/veterinary?q=veterinary) but, curiously,  a few AmE dictionaries such as the [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=veterinary&submit.x=32&submit.y=35) and the [Random House Dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/veterinary)  suggests that veterinary (pl. veterinaries) is also a noun meaning:

> - a veterinarian.

They don’t suggest that it is a regional or a dated usage so I’d like to ask if “veterinary” is currently and commonly used as a noun in AmE unlike in BrE.

Comment: [A **veterinary physician**, usually called a **vet**, which is shortened from **veterinarian** (American English) or **veterinary surgeon** (British English), is a professional who practices veterinary medicine ….](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veterinary_physician)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I am not referring to veterinary as a noun adjunct  usage, quite common by the way both in BrE and AmE, but to ***veterinary*** (pl.  veterinaries) as a noun meaning ***veterinarian*** as the two AmE dictionaries clearly state. Pleas stop the “vet” story. It doesn’t help. Btw..that also means veteran.

Comment: Great question on dialect nuance. To my ear, AmE, (not to give an official answer), the animal physician you take your pet dog to is a veterinarian or vet. If one said I took my dog to the veterinary, I'd expect they'd also use a lorry, have a biscuit for a snack, and go to hospital (ie very BrE, not AmE at all). My next step would be to use Google NGrams comparing veterinary_NOUN vs veterinary_ADJ in gb vs us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before the [emergence in the second half of the 18th c.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veterinary_Medicine#History) of veterinary medicine as an academic discipline, the trade most involved with the care of domestic animals was that of farriers, who shoed horses and along the way acquired basic knowledge of equine injury and disease. The word *veterinarian*, however, from Latin *veterinarius*, ‘person who treats diseases of working animals/cattle’, predates the academic profession, first appearing in a [1646](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veterinary_physician#Etymology_and_nomenclature) work of [Sir Thomas Browne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Browne).

The first institute of veterinary medicine was founded in Lyon in 1762; its graduates were called, as they are today, [*vétérinaires*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A9t%C3%A9rinaire), a likely source for the alternative English *veterinary*. This school was soon followed by others in Vienna and Padova, 1765; Göttingen, 1771, and finally, London in 1790. The [London college](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veterinary_physician#History) was headed by the Frenchman Benoit Vial de St. Bel, who may have given a further boost to nominal *veterinary*.

The earliest example from the UK I could find dates from 1819:

> In Flanders it is effected by the practice of a similar system to that which was first introduced into England, by the useful publication of Strickland Freeman, Esq. and which has been since adopted, and pretty generally circulated through the united kingdom [Belgium], by the works and practice of Mr. Colman and other [*veterinaries*](https://books.google.de/books?id=ikxKAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA220&dq=%22veterinaries%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSh62woc7cAhVChSwKHTmrDJA4FBDoAQhFMAc)…   — Thomas Radcliff, *A Report on the Agriculture of Eastern and Western Flanders*, London,1819, 220.

Querying for the plural conveniently eliminates any attributive use. Although [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/veterinary) suggests an 1861 appearance in North American English of nominal *veterinary*, the word is actually attested some decades earlier in an academic journal:

> But this very success made Priesnitz many enemies; the priests cast anathemas upon his devilish art: the physicians and [*veterinaries*](https://books.google.de/books?id=K5fBue4B9wgC&pg=PA134&dq=%22veterinaries%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJnNH55c7cAhURDuwKHdd6Di04HhDoAQgjMAA) denounced him for practicing illegally, and the authorities were obliged to intervene.  *The Western Journal of the Medical and Physical Sciences*, vol. 12, no. 45, Cincinnati OH, 1838, 134.

*Veterinary* as noun, however, has never enlarged its role as a seldom used alternative to *veterinarian*, a fact reputable dictionaries should have noted in their definitions. Of those American newspapers accessible through elephind.com, [*veterinaries*](https://elephind.com/?a=q&results=1&lcq=&e=-------en-10--1-byDA-txt-txINtxCO-veterinaries------US---) appears 1,015 times compared to 32,179 hits for [*veterinarians*](https://elephind.com/?a=q&r=1&results=1&sf=byDA&e=-------en-10--1--txt-txINtxCO-veterinarians---------). The much more current [iWeb Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/iweb/), now at 14 billion words, shows an even more radical disparity in frequency: *veterinaries*, 19; *veterinarians*, 27,920. Unfortunately, this corpus does not produce search results with a unique URL, so I can provide no links.

Infrequent though it may be, the word still finds use on both sides of the Atlantic:

> Before the treatment begins, a veterinarian who supervises the whole procedure must immobilize the rhino. Hence, one member of the otherwise changing RRP task force is always a veterinarian. South African [*veterinaries*](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/guest-blog/dye-and-poison-stop-rhino-poachers/) use etorphine, which is better known as “M99”. — Martin Angler, *Scientific American* Blog, 9 May 2013.

Here,  nominal *veterinary* avoids using *veterinarian/s* three times in so many sentences. The following article from a small town Texas weekly also uses *vet* and *veterinarian* several times, so nominal *veterinary* can avoid too much repetition here as well:

> Last year 1,497 vaccines were administered to dogs and cats at the rabies clinics. The Cherokee Animal Clinic gave 604 shots, the most in the county. The two [*veterinaries*](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth152833/m1/11/zoom/?q=veterinaries&resolution=4&lat=5594.6944121569895&lon=1805.2116388990655#) there are Dr. Anthony Holcomb and Dr. Justin Novak... — *The Cherokeean* (Rusk TX), 7 May 2008.

A Virginia newpapers uses the word to mean ‘veterinary practice’ or the place of business of a veterinarian:

> The Northern Neck Humane Society will have Holiday Angel Wreaths at businesses and [*veterinaries*](https://virginiachronicle.com/cgi-bin/virginia?a=d&d=RR20041118.1.3&txq=veterinaries) throughout the Northern Neck over the Thanksgiving and Christmas holidays. Parents can place the names of children, pets or loved ones on the wreaths. — *Rappahannock Record* (VA), 18 Nov. 2004.

By the end of the 20th c., the word had not completely vanished from UK English, here making an appearance in a debate in the House of Lords:

> British *[veterinaries](https://books.google.de/books?id=uA9w9jPcgX8C&q=veterinaries&dq=veterinaries&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG1P2pns_cAhVLKuwKHVVsCrg4FBDoAQgrMAI)* are of an extremely high standard. The degree courses are monitored by the Royal College of Veterinary Surgeons under the 1966 Act. — *The Parliamentary Debates (House of Lords)*, 1988.

Even  if someone were reading or hearing nominal *veterinary* for the first time in these sources, the meaning is immediately clear, but the economy of one syllable was not enough for the word to compete with the older and far more frequent *veterinarian*.

Comment: That Virginia newspaper example corresponds to my (AmE) understanding of the nominal usage: a *veterinary* is the place where the *veterinarian* works. Somewhat analogous to how *pediatrics* is where the *pediatrician* works and *ophthalmology* is where the *ophthalmologist* works, except for some reason it's countable.

Answer (score 3):

As a noun, it's become rare but it is not yet obsolete, nor archaic. It appears to be used on both sides of the pond.

> ### Veterinary
>
> NOUN ***dated***
>   A veterinary surgeon.
>   *‘In this year's no 22 of the Swedish magazine Ridsport, [two Norwegian veterinaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/veterinary) reported on a test they had performed themselves.’*
>
> Oxford Living Dictionaries

Google Books

- “The reports of these **two veterinaries** gives an idea of the prevalence of lockjaw among animals. Nearly all of the practicing physicians report no knowledge of the disease among animals” *[Long Island Medical Journal](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2yagAAAAMAAJ&q=%22two%20veterinaries%22&dq=%22two%20veterinaries%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj466-Y_8vcAhWG_p8KHSGQCGoQ6AEIdzAQ)* (Long Island, NY, 1905)
- “At the moment I know of two valuable weight-carrying hunters, on which a well-known sportsman hunts hounds every week, and one was rejected by **several veterinaries** for incipient side bones five years ago, whilst **two veterinaries** pronounced the other a roarer when he was five years old.” [*Practical Hints for Hunting Novices*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wqYyDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT48&dq=%22two%20veterinaries%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj466-Y_8vcAhWG_p8KHSGQCGoQ6AEIYDAL#v=onepage&q=%22two%20veterinaries%22&f=false) (London, 1906)
- “Father immediately sent **two veterinaries** to Kentucky to examine her. They pronounced her not in foal and accordingly she was sold. How wrong those **vets** were!” *[Full Tilt!](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Vq9FAAAAMAAJ&q=%22two%20veterinaries%22&dq=%22two%20veterinaries%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjm-PyggszcAhVEilQKHe3wCSU4KBDoAQh9MBM)* (NY, 1938)

Comment: Yes, I saw the ODO note about the term being  dated, which to me refers more to BrE usage. AmE dictionaries have nothing in that respect, and as a user suggests in a comment veterinary meaning veterinarian  is still used in AmE though it is not common.  I’d like to understand more about AmE usage. I suspect that in places like ranches where cattle are raised veterinary is still common.

Comment: @user070221: You would suspect wrong. If someone raising livestock in the US bothers to use to use the full form rather than _vet_, it's going to be _veterinarian_. An NGram suggests _veterinary_ not used attributively has rarely risen above 0% frequency since 1800. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=veterinaries%2Cveterinarians&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cveterinaries%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cveterinarians%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @KarlG - I think it is mostly a spoken issue, something that Ngram might not detect properly. In any case there is something wrong with those AmE dictionaries, if what you say is true.